# "create-nx-workspace" command not found (linxus and windows10 problem)

Tags: angular, npm, nrwl, nrwl-nx

Can someone please explain me how to setup nrwl/schematics? I'm trying to follow along a course from frontendmasters and they are using nrwl to generate workspace. When I run the same command on my machine (both windows and linux OS) that command is not found

create-nx-workspace someName

Please help me setup this workspace and understand why am I getting this error message. On windows I know that this usually means (not recognized cmdlet) that the PATH to executable is not defined but I have no idea where the path is supposed to be and I couldn't find the answer.

Any help is truly appreciated.
Regards

So far I have tried installing @nrwl/schematics as roo/administrator, reinstaling, rebooting PC, tried the stpes on both Linux and Windows

Answer (score 4):

use npx create-nx-workspace someName

Comment: I am watching the same course, and this one worked for me :)

Comment: I was using Node 10 and it was not working. I upgrade it to 15 and it's work for me.

Answer (score 2):

@nrwl/nx - mentioned in the first answer is deprecated. You need to install @nrwl/cli.

```
npm install -g @nrwl/cli
```

That will make `nx` available on windows path.

Answer (score 1):

First `npm i @nrwl/nx` in your terminal. (I haven't worked with nx but I believe this is required for @nrwl/schematics. Then:
`npm install @nrwl/schematics`

For more - Take a look here, it described the process quite well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nrwl/nx

Note: You can add nx to a current Angular workspace with `ng add @nrwl/schematics` or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

[`create-nx-workspace`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-nx-workspace) module needs to be installed first.

This can be done using the following command:

```
npm install create-nx-workspace
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use npx to create node application. First of all, you have to install some tools which are mention below the commands.

```
npm i -g @nrwl/schematics
npx create-nx-workspace
```

You will have many options to choose the project's framework like angular, react and many more. Choose the requirements of your project and go on.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you have to install some tools use cmd or terminal

> npm i -g @nrwl/schematics

> npm i -g  create-nx-workspace

2. then  create new workspace using

> npm init nx-workspace

complete the following question display on cmd/terminal

? Workspace name (e.g., org name)
? What to create in the new workspace
? CLI to power the Nx workspace.
? Use the free tier of the distributed cache provided by Nx Cloud.